# ¿Cómo hacer un SELECT con múltiples condiciones?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas diferentes (`t1`, `t2`) y necesito realizar un `DELETE` en la `t1` de todos las filas que cumplan que uno de sus campos tenga un valor determinado y ademas también eliminar de t1 todas las lineas que cumplan una condición en t2. Algo como:

```
DELETE * FROM t1 JOIN t2 WHERE t1.c1=0 OR (t1.c2=t2.c1 AND t2.c3=3)
```

motor de BD innoDB

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio. Por favor agrega los tags necesarios para identificar el motor de bases de datos que estás usando, ya que la implementación de `DELETE` muchas veces es diferente dependiendo del motor

Comment: motor de BD innoDB

Comment: @Quarkbite como dice Lamak, agrega los tags, pero no en los comentarios si no en la pregunta [editandola](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/44711/edit)

Comment: Sólo se puede añadir un tag nuevo (innoDB no existe) con más de 150 de reputación. Saludos.

Comment: @pabgaran pero innodb es mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un EXISTS debería funcionarte:

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE t1.c1=0 OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t1.c2=t2.c1 AND t2.c3=3)
```

Comment: Perfecto, me funciono. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE * FROM t1 JOIN t2 WHERE t1.c1=0 OR t1.c2=t2.c1 AND t2.c3=3
```

Los paréntesis no son necesarios dado que `OR` tiene prioridad sobre el `AND`.

Probá usando `INNER JOIN` en lugar de `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

cuando envies una pregunta deberias dar mas detalle. yo haria algo como esto

```
    DELETE FROM t1 WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT id
                                     FROM t1 
                                     INNER JOIN t2 u on t1.id_externo = t1.id
                                   WHERE COLOCA TU CONDICION AQUI)
```

Podria agregar un OR en despues del WHERE

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE t1.id IN (CONSULTA) OR t1.id IN (CONSULTA)
```

Depende del motor se puede optimizar espero que te  sirva